# Not able to deploy Django properly on Cpanel (static part)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, cpanel, web-deployment

I tried all steps and commands to enable the static part when project deployed on Cpanel python app but I failed. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.
Deployed:
[Deployed my codes on Cpanel on goDaddy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNgHW.png)

[Images which are visible are from imported from the Internet not from static file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQtSx.png)

[Expected: (On local machine)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jih7y.jpg)

[I'm able to open each tab in local but getting 404 error on deployed one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ4mT.png)

- views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import ManuForm
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'manufacture_page/homepage.html', {'form': ManuForm()})
    else:
        try:
            form = ManuForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save(commit=True)
                messages.info(request, 'Thanks! Will contact you back.')
                return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
            else:
                print("IN ERROR")

                errmsg= str(form.errors)
                print(errmsg)
                if "Phone already exists" in errmsg:
                    errmsg="Error!! Entered Number already exists!"
                elif "Enter a valid phone number" in errmsg:
                    errmsg="Error!! Enter number with country code. (e.g. +917529984220)."
                else:
                    errmsg="Error!! Bad data passed in!"

                messages.error(request,errmsg)
                # return render(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'], 'homepage.html', {'form': ManuForm(), 'error': errmsg})
                return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'], {'form': ManuForm(), 'error': errmsg})
            return redirect(home)
        except ValueError:
            return render(request, 'manufacture_page/homepage.html', {'form': ManuForm(), 'error':'Bad data passed in!'})

def about(request):
        return render(request, 'manufacture_page/about.html')


def services(request):
    return render(request, 'manufacture_page/services.html')
```

- settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = '2dh-pafar$e$te&(m)b^z&yif035l1q=gid!q%$*+#l6r*&%*x'

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['prezotech.in']



INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'manufacture_page',
    'phonenumber_field',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'lable_manufacturer.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'lable_manufacturer.wsgi.application'


# Database

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/


STATICFILES_DIRS=[BASE_DIR+"/static"]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

- urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from manufacture_page import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home),
    path('homepage.html', views.home),
    path('about.html', views.about),
    path('services.html', views.services),
    path('homepage.html#newsletter', views.home),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

- homepage.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->


  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/solid.css" integrity="sha384-v2Tw72dyUXeU3y4aM2Y0tBJQkGfplr39mxZqlTBDUZAb9BGoC40+rdFCG0m10lXk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "/manufacture_page/style.css" %}">

     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{% static "/manufacture_page/logo.png" %}">
  <title>Label manufacturer</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- logo -->
      <a href="" class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/523F1fP/poster5-20-12359-1.png"  width="45" height="35">
      </a>

      <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Prezotech</a>
      <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=917529984220" style="font-size:17px;color:grey">
<!--        Send Message</a>-->
<!--      <a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello World!&phone=+917529984220">-->
<!--        <i class="fa fa-whatsapp style="font-size:22px;color:blue" " aria-hidden="true"></i>-->
        Send Msg <i class="fa fa-whatsapp" style="font-size:23px;color:#25D366; "></i>
      </a>


      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="homepage.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="about.html" class="nav-link">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="services.html" class="nav-link">Products & Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href = "#newsletter" class="nav-link">Connect with Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- SHOWCASE SLIDER -->
  <section id="showcase">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item carousel-image-1 ">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-sm-block text-right mb-5 text-dark">
              <h1 class="brown_bk"><span>Contact Us</span></h1>
              <p class="lead"><span>
                Phone Number:
                  General Query: +91 9990768844 <br>
                  Sales Team: +91 9990764567<br>
                  Manufacturing Team: +91 9990768876<br>
                  Technical Team: +91 9990768833
              </span></p>
              <a href="https://www.prezotech.com/enquiry.html" target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Contact Details</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item carousel-image-2">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-sm-block mb-5">
              <h1 class="brown_bk"><span>Reviews</span></h1>
              <p class="lead"><span>We have the most satisfied customers.
                Check out customers review in different sites.</span></p>
              <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&tbm=lcl&sxsrf=ALeKk01Q1Rq0ZRY_DswG94FRSh3b8_7qFg%3A1591739597842&ei=zQTgXs_3Mt_S1fAP3OakmAo&q=prezotech+solutions+private+limited&oq=Prezotech+sol&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.35i39k1l2j0.878.1332.0.2388.4.4.0.0.0.0.128.386.3j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.4.386...0i30k1.0.a1stxb_bjpo#rlfi=hd:;si:17620352125786189722,l,CiNwcmV6b3RlY2ggc29sdXRpb25zIHByaXZhdGUgbGltaXRlZEjUysywg6uAgAhaWgojcHJlem90ZWNoIHNvbHV0aW9ucyBwcml2YXRlIGxpbWl0ZWQQABABEAIQAxgAGAEYAhgDIiNwcmV6b3RlY2ggc29sdXRpb25zIHByaXZhdGUgbGltaXRlZA;mv:[[28.633411,77.31693310000001],[28.629303200000003,77.31207959999999]]"
                 class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"> Google</a>
              <a target="_blank" href="https://www.justdial.com/Delhi/Prezotech-Solutions-Pvt-Ltd-Near-Nexa-Maruti-Showroom-Ghazipur/011PXX11-XX11-171218141608-Q5M6_BZDET/reviews/page-20?xid=THVkaGlhbmEgV292ZW4gTGFiZWwgTWFudWZhY3R1cmVycyBMb2xheQ=="
                 class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"> JustDial</a>
              <a target="_blank" href="https://www.indiamart.com/prezotech/testimonial.html"
                 class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"> IndiaMart</a>
              <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/Prezotech/reviews/?ref=page_internal"
                 class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"> Facebook</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="carousel-item carousel-image-3 active">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption  d-sm-block text-right mb-5">
              <h1 class="brown_bk"><span>Prezotech Label Manufacturer</span></h1>
              <p class="lead"><span>Leader in the field of label manufacturing and Barcode related solution provider.</span></p>
              <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Learn More About Us</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" class="carousel-control-prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
      </a>

      <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" class="carousel-control-next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!--HOME ICON SECTION  -->
  <section id="home-icons" class="py-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 text-center">
          <i class="fas fa-handshake fa-3x mb-2"></i>
          <h3><b>TRUST!</b></h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Libero, veniam.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 text-center">
          <i class="fas fa-user-lock fa-3x mb-2"></i>
          <h3><b>COMMITMENT!</b></h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Libero, veniam.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4 text-center">
          <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-3x mb-2"></i>
          <h3><b>QUALITY!</b></h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Libero, veniam.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- HOME HEADING SECTION -->
  <section id="home-heading" class="p-5">
    <div class="dark-overlay">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="container pt-5">
            <h1>Our Motto: Customer First!</h1>
            <p class="d-none d-md-block">
              "Happy customers are your biggest advocates and can become your most successful sales team."
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- INFO SECTION -->
  <section id="info" class="py-3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
          <h3>Our Team is Our Family!</h3>
          <p>With a bunch of experienced team members and Japanese machines we deliver standard and on time
            label with any size demanded.</p>
          <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg">Learn More</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="{% static "/manufacture_page/label.gif" %}" alt="" class="img-fluid">


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- VIDEO PLAY -->
  <section id="video-play">
    <div class="dark-overlay">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="container p-5">
            <a href="#" class="video" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cafgEkr2wcc" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal">
              <i class="fas fa-play fa-3x"></i>
            </a>
            <h1>See What We Do</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- PHOTO GALLERY -->
  <section id="gallery" class="py-5">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="text-center">Photo Gallery</h1>
      <p class="text-center">Check out our photos</p>
      <div class="row mb-4">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <a href="{% static "/manufacture_page/one.jpg" %}" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="img-gallery" data-height="560"
            data-width="560">
            <img src="{% static "/manufacture_page/one.jpg" %}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <a href="{% static "/manufacture_page/two.png" %}" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="img-gallery" data-height="561"
            data-width="561">
            <img src="{% static "/manufacture_page/two.png" %}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <a href="{% static "/manufacture_page/three.jpg" %}" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="img-gallery" data-height="562"
            data-width="562">
            <img src="{% static "/manufacture_page/three.jpg" %}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row mb-4">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <a href="{% static "/manufacture_page/four.jpg" %}" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="img-gallery" data-height="563"
            data-width="563">
            <img src="{% static "/manufacture_page/four.jpg" %}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <a href="{% static "/manufacture_page/five.png" %}" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="img-gallery" data-height="564"
            data-width="564">
            <img src="{% static "/manufacture_page/five.png" %}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <a href="{% static "/manufacture_page/six.jpeg" %}" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="img-gallery" data-height="565"
            data-width="565">
            <img src="{% static "/manufacture_page/six.jpeg" %}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- NEWSLETTER -->


  <section id="newsletter" class="text-center p-5 bg-dark text-white">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class ="newsletter1 {% if active_tab == 'newsletter1' %} active{% endif %}">

            <label><h1>Get In Touch</h1></label>

<!--            <h2>{{ error }}</h2>-->

               {% for message in messages %}

                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                        <a class="close" href="#" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>

                       <h6> {{ message }} </h6>

                    </div>
            {% endfor %}


            <form method="POST" class="form-inline justify-content-center">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control mb-2 mr-2" placeholder="Enter Name" id="name" required>
                <input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control mb-2 mr-2" placeholder="Enter Phone" id="phone" required>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control mb-2 mr-2" placeholder="Enter Email" id="email" >
                <input type="text" name="query" class="form-control mb-2 mr-2" placeholder="Any Query?" id="query">
            <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2" type="submit">Send</button>

            </form>
          </div>

            <br>
<!--          Social media-->

          <li class="nav-item ml-auto active">
            <a href="https://www.prezotech.com/" class="nav-link" >
              <input type="image" src="https://i.ibb.co/kchdgsK/poster5-23-205140-1.png" />
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ml-auto">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/prezotech/" class="nav-link"><i class="fab fa-instagram" style="font-size:32px;color:red"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ml-auto">
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKwa5sBdl0_afSyGJTT4Nvg" class="nav-link"><i class="fab fa-youtube" style="font-size:32px;color:red" ></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ml-auto">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Prezotech" class="nav-link"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f" style="font-size:27px;color:blue" ></i></a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item ml-auto">
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/prezotech/?originalSubdomain=in" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" style="font-size:29px;color:blue" ></i></a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item ml-auto">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/prezotechsol" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-twitter" style="font-size:29px;color:blue" ></i></a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item ml-auto">
            <a href="http://prezotech.in/feedback" class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-comment-dots" style="font-size:29px;color:purple" ></i></a>
          </li>






        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <footer id="main-footer" class="text-center p-4">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <p>Copyright &copy;
            <span id="year"></span> Prezotech</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>


  <!-- VIDEO MODAL -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="videoModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
            <span>&times;</span>
          </button>
          <iframe src="" frameborder="0" height="350" width="100%" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    // Get the current year for the copyright
    $('#year').text(new Date().getFullYear());

    // Configure Slider
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 6000,
      pause: 'hover'
    });

    // Lightbox Init
    $(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).ekkoLightbox();
    });

    // Video Play
    $(function () {
      // Auto play modal video
      $(".video").click(function () {
        var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
          videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-video"),
          videoSRCauto = videoSRC + "?modestbranding=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&html5=1&autoplay=1";
        $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
        $(theModal + ' button.close').click(function () {
          $(theModal + ' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
        });
      });
    });

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ae3Hx.png)

[enter link description here](http://prezotech.in/Prezotech_Manufacturer)

P.S: I have already used **collectstatic**

Answer (score 1):

Run this command to build all the static files:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

After this, a static folder containing all the required static files will be created at the project root. Just upload that folder onto cPanel and paste the URL back in your Django app.

Comment: Thank you so much @Aayushi Shah, just want to clarify what do you mean by **and paste the URL back in your Django app.?**